# Maximization of function using Newton-Raphson Method

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, optimization, newton-raphson, quadratic-programming

This is a homework problem.

We need to prove that when we apply the Newton-Raphson method to strictly quadratic concave function. It will converge in one step.

How to apply this method to maximization of

$$f(x) = 4\cdot x_1 + 6\cdot x_2 - 2\cdot x_1^2 - 2\cdot  x_1\cdot x_2 - 2 \cdot x_2^2$$

I did not understand how to apply method to this function? what should be the interval?

Comment: Newton's method just has a starting point, not a domain, but in this case the whole idea is that the starting point doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an interval.  You are using Newton-Raphson to find a solution of the system
$$ \eqalign{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} &= 4 - 4 x_1 - 2 x_2 = 0\cr 
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} &= 6 - 2 x_1 - 4 x_2 = 0\cr}$$
This being a linear system, it doesn't matter where your initial point is: Newton-Raphson simply solves the linear system.

Comment: So what is the general method for any function any relevant reading?